# How to reset the source and keep the binding possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my solution I use specific class which contains a collection of some elements. When I want to Binding this collection I usually use a such path `{Binding MyClass.InnerCollection}`. It works fine before that moment when I will try to set another instance for that class, and than it's could not be binded.

**Question**: How to reset the source and keep the binding possible. Is it possible to reset the source without losing the binding without changing `ItemsSource` directly?

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Container.InnerCollection}"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <Button Content="Add new item" Click="AddNewItem"/>
        <Button Content="Reset source" Click="ResetSource"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Container = new MyClass() { InnerCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Start" } };

        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public MyClass Container { get; set; }

    public void AddNewItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Container.InnerCollection.Add($"AddedItem");
    }
    public void ResetSource(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Container = new MyClass() { InnerCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>() { $"Reseted" } };
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> InnerCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't reset `Container`, reset `Container.InnerCollection`

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I know that if I reset only InnerCollection, everything will work fine. But 
time to time I reset this source (with Serialize and Deserialize)

Comment: `this.BindingContext = new MyClass() { InnerCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Start" } };`

Comment: The Container property must fire the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Answer (score 0):

Let's reset only what you need to reset:

```
public void ResetSource(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Container.InnerCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>() { $"Reseted" };
}
```

Comment: This would require that MyClass also implements INotifyPropertyChanged and fires the PropertyChanged event  when its InnerCollection property changes.

Comment: @Clemens of course it does! I assume the ts knows what he/she is doing.

Comment: That is perhaps a false assumption...